# PIP fails to install packages with error code 1

Tags: python, cmd, pip

I have Python 3.7 installed on my PC and I also have PIP installed. I need to install a package (auto-py-to-exe) but everytime I try, it fails:

```
Command "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hju2c6l9\\gevent\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-vca2l5gm\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hju2c6l9\gevent\
```

I have tried uninstalling auto-py-to-exe and reinstalling it but this error msg keeps appearing. I have also tried other packages and the same happens.

Attempting to run auto-py-to-exe after a failed install brings up the error:

```
raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers) pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'gevent' distribution was not found and is required by gevent-websocket
```

pip install gevent also fails as before

Thanks for any help

(I am on Windows 10, running python 3.7 with pip version 18.0)

Comment: Please post the complete error. What you've added is a generic error that doesn't help.

Comment: That is the complete error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to run the command with Admin privileges and change the location to `/c` and then install "*auto-py-to-exe*" , or update your pip with `pip install --update` , to ensure your using the latest version of the installer.

Comment: Unfortunately I am unable to run in admin at the moment :(

Comment: pip install --update fails with error:  no such option: --update

Comment: oh .. :( that's a bad new, I had a similar issue installing `pyperclip` , and i had to use admin privileges, or other way is trying to install the program with `pip` directly from the IDLE terminal console, worked on `pycharm` :D !!! wish you good luck buddy hope you find the solution!!!

Comment: I decided in the end to use PyInstaller and download it from github - seemed to work ok

Comment: try pip install --upgrade pip